# Global array loses values after exiting method

Tags: objective-c, arrays, global-variables

At the top of my .m file I have

```
static NSMutableArray *name;
```

I load a bunch of values into my *name array inside my viewDidLoad method.

I have a slider that can modify the values inside this array.  The slider method is only called when the value of the slider changes.  However, I ran this code and every time my program exits the viewDidLoad method I lose the values that were added to the global variable name.  I can see that they were there before exiting the viewDidLoad method.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Inside viewDidLoad

```
if (name == nil)
    name = [NSMutableArray array];
UITextField *nameTemp = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)];
nameTemp.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
etc
[self.view addSubview: nameTemp];
[name addObject:nameTemp]
[nameTemp release];
```

Comment: Post the code of what you are doing in `viewDidLoad` method. If I amn't wrong, you aren't making a deep copy to `name`. Or having a reference to local variable.

Comment: Posted it.  Suggestions?

Comment: Stupid questions: 1. Did you ever actually create the NSMutableArray? 2. Did you retain the NSMutableArray? 3. Is the code where you create the NSMutableArray (assuming you do) executed only once, or do you execute it repeatedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSMutableArray array]` creates an autoreleased array that apparently is being released at the end of your `viewDidLoad` method. Try using `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` or `[[NSMutableArray array] retain]` and see if the values persist after `viewDidLoad` returns.

Comment: That got it.  I guess I need to look up autoreleasing since I don't understand it.  I would have thought that declaring it as a global would be enough.

Comment: Ah yeah, I thought that might be the case. Remember that what you've done is declared a static *variable* which is actually a pointer to an object, and not a static object itself. The static-ness of the variable makes sure that the variable lives for the lifetime of the program, but makes no guarantee about the object that it refers to.